# Which is the correct text datatype to use in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, text, types, char, varchar

There's VARCHAR, CHAR, TEXT, BIGTEXT, BLOB...

Which is the correct datatype to use when storing small text fields (ie. something like `first_name`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Correct" is a strong word, but most people would probably use `VARCHAR`. `CHAR` is also an option, but it's not as frequently used in my experience. [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) explains the difference.

One of the notable differences between `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` in the latest versions of MySQL is that `CHAR` is incapable of storing trailing spaces (because the column is automatically padded to its max length by spaces). So if you store something like `'abc '`, it will be retrieved as `'abc'`. This might not matter for most applications, but it's something to keep in mind. Similarly, prior to 5.03, trailing whitespaces are stripped from `VARCHAR` fields before insertion. So if you need to store arbitrary byte values and don't want to worry about different behaviors between MySQL versions, you should use one of the [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) types.

Answer (score 3):

I usually go with VARCHAR for most small text fields, unless I know the field is going to be a fixed size, like a U.S. state abbreviation, where I'd use CHAR(2).